# SQL Case Statement NULL column

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

```
proc SQL;


CREATE TABLE DATA.DUMMY AS
SELECT *,  
  CASE 
  WHEN (Discount IS NOT NULL) 
    THEN (Total_Retail_Price - (Total_Retail_Price * Discount)) * Quantity AS Rev
  ELSE (Total_Retail_Price * Quantity) AS Rev
  END

FROM DATA.Cumulative_Profit_2013 AS P

;
```

I am trying to factor in a potentially NULL column as part of the expression for Revenue. But my case statement throws up issues. I've checked other examples, but I can't see a why that would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can use [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to achieve your goal without an explicit conditional:

```
SELECT *,  
  (Total_Retail_Price - (Total_Retail_Price * COALESCE(Discount, 0))) * Quantity AS Rev
FROM DATA.Cumulative_Profit_2013 AS P
```

Comment: be careful Discount(Discount, 0)

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing SAS the normal SQL syntax would be:

```
SELECT *,  
  CASE 
   WHEN (Discount IS NOT NULL) 
    THEN (Total_Retail_Price - (Total_Retail_Price * Discount)) * Quantity 
   ELSE (Total_Retail_Price * Quantity)
  END AS Rev
```

That is, with the column alias after the end of the case expression.

Comment: You also can add a `COALESCE` before the `CASE` to avoid any `NULL` fields in the Rev column if that is what you are looking for.  Something like this `COALESCE(CASE WHEN ....... END, 0) AS Rev`.

Comment: @CrApHeR Indeed, good point. The other answer demonstrates the usage of coalesce though so I won't add it to mine.

Answer (score 1):

As a note, I would write this as:

```
SELECT p.*,  
       (Total_Retail_Price * (1 - COALESCE(Discount, 0)) * Quantity) AS Rev 
FROM DATA.Cumulative_Profit_2013 AP
```

I find the repetition of `Total_Retail_Price` in the original expression harder to follow.

Note:  all the of the answers work in SAS.